# Servlet send response to JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="WelcomeServlet">
<br><br>
<table align="center"><tr><td><h2>Login Authentication</h2></td></tr></table>
<table width="300px" align="center" style="border:1px solid #000000;background-color:#efefef;">
<tr><td colspan=2></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Login Name</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Password</b></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

then this servlet

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
//import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import javax.servlet.*;
//import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
//import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
/* 
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
super.init(config);
}
 */

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
/*
* Get the value of form parameter
*/
response.setContentType("text/html");

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
//out.println("I am on welcome servlet...");
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password =request.getParameter("password");

out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head>");
         out.println("<title> A very simple servlet example</title>");
         out.println("</head>");
          out.println("<body>");
            out.println("</body>");

      if((username.equals("kiran"))&&(password.equals("kiran")))
       {

         String welcomeMessage = "Welcome "+username+" thanks for login...";
         out.println("<h1>"+welcomeMessage+"</h1>");
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").include(request, response);

    }else
      {
         out.println("<h1> You are not the valid user...</h1>");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").include(request, response);

        }

            out.println("</html>");
            out.close();





}

public void destroy() {

}
}
```

I want a response from servet which is display below the jsp page  login authetication table

Answer (score 42):

That's not entirely right. In contrary to what lot of basic servlet tutorials try to let you believe, the [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) should **not** be used to output pure HTML. This contradicts the MVC ideology. There the [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) should be used for.

In this particular case, you need to let the servlet set the message which you'd like to display in the JSP in the request scope and then *forward* the request/response to the JSP. In the JSP, you can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to dynamically control the HTML output and use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) `${}` to access and display the message.

Here's a kickoff example of how the servlet should look like:

```
public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String message = null;

        if ((username.equals("kiran")) && (password.equals("kiran"))) {
            message = "Welcome "+username+" thanks for login...";
        } else {
            message = "You are not the valid user...";
        }
    
        request.setAttribute("message", message);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

and edit your `login.jsp` to add the following:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

...

<c:if test="${not empty message}">
    <h1>${message}</h1>
</c:if>
```

The taglib declaration has to go in the top. The `<c:if>` can just be positioned exactly there where you'd like to display the `<h1>`.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - Contains a Hello world which covers basic validation.