# Avoiding html in servlet

Tags: java, html, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm on a jsp page and I am doing an ajax call to a servlet which in return provides full html code to be displayed on  page. It works fine but looks cluttered in servlet file to have multiple `printWriter.write(...)` lines with html code in it. It becomes hard to maintain as I have to create a large html code via servlet. Is there any other proper/better way to do this?  I have cmobination of write html lines and logic in servlet and it will be hard to separate them.

The ajax call in jsp page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myServlet',
    data: requestData,
    dataType: "text",
}).done(function(responseData) {
    $(divId).html(responseData);
});
```

Some code from servlet class:

```
.....
String username = user.getName();
if (username != null && !username.trim().isEmpty())
    username = username.substring(0, username.indexOf(" "));
else
    username = "";
printWriter.write("<span id=\"username_"+i+"\" style=\"display: none;\">"+ username +"</span>");
printWriter.write("<form action=\"\" method=\"post\" name=\"userClickForm_"+i +"\" id=\"userClickForm_"+i +"\">");
printWriter.write(" <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"userId\" value=\""+userId +"\"/>");
printWriter.write("</form>");
......
```

The main reason of mixing html code and business logic is I have to provide div id based on conditions and loop structure.

Comment: a simple solution is to write the html page in  a file and retrieve it in a loop using a InputStream

Comment: @Bhavik: That's a very bad advice. Why reinventing the wheel if JSP has already been invented for that? It also allows much easier interweaving with scoped attributes by EL and output flow control by JSTL.

Comment: @BalusC : I don't know much  about ajax and JSTL. How can we access scoped variables sent by ajax response? my main aim of that advise is for this reason  `It becomes hard to maintain` of the OP. so if he reads from a file, it would be easy to maintain files

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452537/servlet-send-response-to-jsp?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

You should use some form of template or transformation technology. Since you're using jQuery and JSPs this can be either a server-side JSP or a client-side jQuery template plugin.

Early JSP MVC patterns take this form:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException {
    // read inputs
    String foo = request.getParameter("foo");
    // perform business logic
    SomeResults results = new SomeDataSource().lookupDatabase(foo);
    // place results into scope
    request.setAttribute("results", results);
    // dispatch to JSP to render results
    request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp")
           .forward(request, response);
}
```

This approach can be used with an AJAX call.

Alternatively, you can respond with JSON or XML data and parse this in the JavaScript, then use a JavaScript template engine to do something similar to the logic performed in the JSP.

Comment: Please note that JSPs can perfectly fine just return a partial of HTML code. I.e. you do absolutely not necessarily need to put a whole `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><body>` and so on in the JSP. It's perfectly legit to let the JSP produce just a `<div>` or so. The OP, who is apparently already familiar with JSP, perhaps didn't see the *obvious* solution immediately due to that.

Comment: @BalusC - Good point. I assumed it was obvious, but perhaps I assume too much.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid that by using MVC framework like STRUTS or SPRING.

Answer (score 1):

Use xml rather than html on servlet and on jsp use success attribute of ajax call using jquery.... In my case its working, bt i have used type as 'GET'.

```
  $.ajax({
            url: ,
            data: ,
            type: ,
            dataType: 'xml',
            async: true,
            success:function(xmlDoc) 
            {   
                var message = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("message");
                message = message[0].firstChild.data;

            }
    });
```

And in Servlet use::

```
         res.getWriter().write("<response><message>abcdefg</message></response>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSP's. It will be on different pair of servlet/jsp request, not the request initiating ajax call.