# Can i Disable Button of JSP from the servlet coding

Tags: jsp, servlets

I need to to code like

in Servlet
  if condition true
     then jsp button is disable= false
  else
     then jsp button is disable = true

So how can i access jsp button object in servlet file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by JSP button? A HTML `<button>`?

If so then set a boolean to your JSP context which describes if the button is disabled or not and in your JSP write:

```
<% if (thisBooleanYouSet) { %>
   <button disabled="disabled">Click Me!</button>
<% } else { %>
   <button>Click Me!</button>
<% } %>
```

Or even better(cleaner), use expression language for the if/else statement.

It all goes down to question of how to pass variables from servlets to JSP. But this is question is too broad to answer here. 
This SO might get you started: [Servlet send response to JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452537/servlet-send-response-to-jsp)