# RequestDispatcher incude method issues

Tags: java, servlets

Hi i am new to java web..
I found a problem that when i am using `RequestDispatcher` `include` method it shows the `html code` in the browser rather in a formatted manner.
i have used like

```
out.println("Username or Password Invalid");
            RequestDispatcher send = request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.html");
            send.include(request, response);
```

and the output shows the entire `Home.html` code with the messaage `Username or Password Invalid.`

I googled and found suggestion that to use `forward` method instead of `inculde`.

if i am using `forward` method then how to include the response message like `Username or Password Invalid.` ???

Please give me some valuable suggestions...Thank You.

Comment: I would take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452537/servlet-send-response-to-jsp

Comment: Biswa in brief just replace "include" by "forwad"..keep everything else same..it would work