# No reply from web application java servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, netbeans

I'm trying to do my first web application with netbeans. It is a simple registration form that is using a servlet and should connect to a mysql database (i'm using phpmyadmin with xampp).

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="register">
        Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
        Email ID:<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
        Password:<input type="text" name="pass" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="register" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Register.java

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        try{

        //loading drivers for mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //creating connection with the database 
          Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                     ("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3309/test","root","");

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
                  ("insert into Student values(?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, email);
        ps.setString(3, pass);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();

          if(i>0)
          {
            out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
          }

        }
        catch(Exception se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
  }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app  version="3.0" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Register</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When i start it, i can see the registration form but trying to insert data, the browser show an empty page at : http://localhost:8084/First_2/register
Is there any way to see what's the error?? Because actually i don't see any from netbeans.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452537/servlet-send-response-to-jsp

Answer (score -1):

in J2EE web applications it is important to config your database datasource on the application server, so you do not have to use a DriverManager directly, instead you should benefit of using connection pools.
If you make use of tomcat app server you may configure the datasource as a global resource on the server.xml descriptor under the globalresources section.
See
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/globalresources.html

The datasource is registered through JNDI (java naming system) and retrieved later on your code using a simple call.

A global resource can then be reused by different applications using a resource reference on the context.xml descriptor /META-INF/context.xml

About using datasources through JNDI on your code you can have a good tutorial here:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Also I think XAMPP is not your friend if you want build a J2EE based web application, XAMPP is a php dev environment non a Java one !

If you use Netbeans you have relevant tutorials in it as well !

Comment: While this is helpful information, it doesn’t answer the question. If you look at the code he’s not sending back a response or a redirect, hence the blank page and no error. The code is doing exactly what it’s supposed to do.

Comment: As Jason said to avoid a blank page you should write a content using response.getWriter().write("...content..."); or include a predefined content as follows:  request.getRequestDispatcher("...new url...").include(request, response);